# How to calculate SQL server stored procedure execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure.
I want to check how much time it takes to execute.
Please note that I don't have access to profiler.
I am using SQL server 2005

I tried using the following batch query

```
SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 121)
EXEC cif_query_trans_by_card_Final2 '0060F423F28A6095AD070CEFFD7E81D245D7D0CD7B', '11223345'
SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 121)
```

But I am getting same value in both timestamp as 2014-12-30 18:09:52.653

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting same values? Simple batch: `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 121)
waitfor delay '00:00:02'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 121)` gives two values differs exactly in two seconds - as it was stated in `delay`. If your timestamps are really the same - the only way I can imagine - that your `cif_query_trans_by_card_Final2` executes for 0 milliseconds(for example, it does nothing). ;)

Comment: Hi Andy,
Thanks for your reply.
My stored procedure is returning 2 rows.
So saying that it is executing for 0 miliseconds is not possible.
I think due to very small resultset I am getting same value.
I think I need to go down with small unit like nanoseconds or so.
But I am not sure if SQL server 2005 supports that.

Comment: `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`

Comment: Hi gvee how to use SET STATISTICS TIME ON?

Comment: Also, why are you converting to varchar? Seems very unnecessary.

Comment: @Sachin Open a new query window, run `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`. Now run your stored procedure. Switch to the *Messages* window to see the results.

Comment: Hi Gvee I am getting the following stats
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

(2 row(s) affected)
Table 'post_tran_cust'. Scan count 0, logical reads 8, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'post_tran'. Scan count 5, logical reads 30, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

Comment: I am not able to get the details about this output

Comment: "Elapsed time 1ms" ... that would seem like a good thing!

Answer (score 4):

## `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190287.aspx**

> When SET STATISTICS TIME is ON, the time statistics for a statement are displayed. When OFF, the time statistics are not displayed.
>
> The setting of SET STATISTICS TIME is set at execute or run time and not at parse time.

1. Open a new query window
2. Run the following SQL `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`
3. In the same window, now run your stored procedure
4. Switch to the `Messages` window to see the resultant statistics

Example:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(65536 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 15 ms,  elapsed time = 272 ms.
```

Comment: Hi Gvee is there any way I can get time in smaller unit like nanoseconds?

Answer (score 1):

Use like below:

```
set statistics time on

-- your query

set statistics time off
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place 2 GO:

```
SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 121)
GO
EXEC cif_query_trans_by_card_Final2 '0060F423F28A6095AD070CEFFD7E81D245D7D0CD7B', '11223345'
GO
SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 121)
```

But: even without your function you will se a delay of few milliseconds.

Comment: Hi Man after using 2 go's it is now giving 2 different timestamps. I wonder if difference between those 2 will be execution time?

Comment: Pretty much. I mean: you have also to consider time needed to communicate with your client.
Probably your function is fast. The problem? A lot of executions? If there is a performance problem the only real way to study it is via trace.